# Most efficient way to check if all timestamps in a Pandas DataFrame index are Business Days

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame. How can I check, explicitly, whether each date in the index is a business day?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}, index=['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-05'])

df

>>>     col_1
2020-01-01  1
2020-01-02  2
2020-01-03  3
2020-01-04  4
2020-01-05  5
```

I realise I could create an index using `pd.bdate_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max())` and compare the lengths of the index, however, I would ideally like to create a separate column that denotes 1 if the date is a business day else 0. I could then sum over axis 0 as a test.

Are there any methods that exist to perform this, that I could apply using `.map()`?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) with casting to integers:

```
df['test'] = df.index.isin(pd.bdate_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max())).astype(int)
print (df)
            col_1  test
2020-01-01      1     1
2020-01-02      2     1
2020-01-03      3     1
2020-01-04      4     0
2020-01-05      5     0
```

Alternative with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['test'] = np.where(df.index.isin(pd.bdate_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max())), 1, 0)
```

Comment: Ah, why didn't I think of that? Thank you very much!